# Share some logic between Backbone.Marionette views

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Previously, I made a backbone view for handling a toggle button:

```js
Star = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click': 'toggle'
  },

  toggle: function() {
    this.$('i').toggleClass('icon-star').toggleClass('icon-star-empty');
  },

  status: function() {
    return this.$el.hasClass('active');
  }
});
```

And i was using this subview in my views like this:

```js
initialize: function() {
    var star = new Star({ el: this.$('.new .btn.star') });
    // ...
}
```

This way i can reuse this subview in many other independent views in backbone. (FYI: I'm no backbone expert. This code also can be wrong. Please correct me if it's wrong.)

Now i'm trying to learn Backbone.Marionette and i couldn't find a good way to accomplish same functionality. How can i use this view in my ItemViews and/or CompositeViews?

Comment: There is no reason you can't continue to do the same thing with `Marionette`. Another option would be to use your `Star` view with a `Marionette.Layout`/`Regions`.

Comment: Without seeing the containing view's code it's difficult to give specifics on how you might take advantage of Marionette's Collection or Composite Views. Would you post that, along with and model and / or collection definitions?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the exact same idea, just extend (e.g.) a Marionette `ItemView`:

```
Star = Marionette.ItemView.extend({...});
```

and then

```
var star = new Star({ el: this.$('.new .btn.star') });
```

Another option is to `extend` your `Star` view:

```
MyView = Star.extend({...});
```